# How to create a pure css slideshow?

Tags: css

On square space when I access my galleries through an index images can only be viewed as 'stacked' and I want to be able to view them in a slideshow but there's no option accept to do custom CSS, which I have never done before. Where should i start?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: You can start by [Googling](https://www.google.com?q=pure+css+slideshow&gws_rd=cr&ei=Ghi5VJXfIIrgywOttIG4Dw#q=pure+css+slideshow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uocyfn69/1/)

```css
#container{
    background:green;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img{
    
    -webkit-animation:up 20s infinite;
}

.img{
    height:300px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes up{
    0%{transform:translate(0,0)}
    20%{transform:translate(0,-300px)}
     40%{transform:translate(0,-600px)}
     60%{transform:translate(0,-900px)}
     80%{transform:translate(0,-1200px)}
    100%{transform:translate(0,-1500px)}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="img ">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301">
</div>
<div class="img ">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/302">
</div>
<div class="img ">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/303">
</div>
<div class="img ">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/304">
</div>
<div class="img  ">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/305">
</div>
    <div class="img  ">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/306">
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an animation to to let them fade in and set the delay on each element a little higher to create time to read the slide